# Create SVG paths for custom clipper flutter

Tags: flutter, svg

I'm trying to implement a curve design in my flutter app as shown in the image

[image]

In my quest to solve this, I have spent 6+ hours to implement it but still got nowhere...

This is how I tried using CustomClipper to get my desired output. but no svg put here looks like what I've shared below!

```
class BackgroudClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    final double _xScaling = size.width / 414;
    final double _yScaling = size.height / 896;
    // svg here
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    // TODO: implement shouldReclip
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

I want to generate svg paths for any kind of image and after doing some research, used a few apps like gimp, illustrator and some online apps too to achieve the same but none of my efforts are leading me anywhere..

I have designed an image myself...

[image]

It has a linear gradient color...

Can somebody please guide me as to how to produce svg paths for such designs!!

Or is there any better way to handle this. All your suggestions are welcomed!!

Thank you.

Comment: "but none of my efforts are leading me anywhere.." - post your code then

Comment: I've added the main bit of the code above... only the line where svg path had to be written is commented!!

Comment: check https://pub.dev/documentation/path_drawing/ - they say: "Currently supports parsing a Path from an SVG path data string"

Comment: it says that it can parse a svg path. the problem is to generate the path in the first place. I think the code that I've shared is enough for parsing too!!

Comment: "I want to generate svg paths for any kind of image"... this is part of the original question!!

Comment: use the package I linked above: it parses SVG path data and returns `Path` object - this is what you want to return from `getClip` method, you even have an example in the above documentation